# It seems like key repeat lags--not picking up multiple quick keyboard strikes. Is this Android specific or Hardware specific?

Tags: keyboard, htc-thunderbolt

On my HTC Thunderbolt, when I type the same character twice, it seems like there is a lag.  The response time is off compared to my iPhone 4G.  On my iphone, the only touchscreen that I used up until the Thunderbolt, you can quickly type without worrying about your keystroke not being read by the phone has having striked twice.

I am interested to see if others have had a similar experience with their Android phones--being a little slow on the key repeat issue.  Would this be something particular to a settings or just a UI convention?

Answer (score 1):

Right now my HTC EVO does not have this issue.  However I have noticed from time to time that the typing something in the virtual keyboard can be slower than usual.  Usually though this is due to an app being installed or I'm switching around in several apps really fast and the lag doesn't last more than the first one or two key selections.

If you haven't already I recommend calibrating your virtual keyboard (it may help it may not :)) In "Settings" go to "Language & Keyboard" then select the input keyboard you are using (I have three different ones on mine you will most likely have less).  My guess is that yours will be called "Touch Input".  From there select "Text Input" and scroll to find "Calibration tool".

Quick Summary: To calibrate your HTC virtual keyboard - "Settings" > "Language & Keyboard" > "Touch Input" > "Text Input" > "Calibration tool"

There may be slight differences due to the fact that the device I'm using is different but since they are both from HTC it should be close.

Hope this helps